# Print range of rows if a condition is met in AWK

Tags: linux, awk

What I am trying to do is to show 2 rows above and 2 rows below a line that meets a certain criteria without a pipe, using awk. For example, I am searching for the string 's62234' and when found, I want to print all the rows bounded in the blue rectangle as shown in the attached screenshot.

This is the file I am using (thefmifile.txt)

```
s62098:x:1271:504:Velizar Vrabchev,SI,3,1:/home/SI/s62098:/bin/bash
s62101:x:1272:504:Georgi Georgiev,SI,3,5:/home/SI/s62101:/bin/bash
s62108:x:1273:504:Sherif Kunch,SI,3,1:/home/SI/s62108:/bin/bash
s62111:x:1274:504:Yulian Bizeranov,SI,3,3:/home/SI/s62111:/bin/bash
s62121:x:1275:504:Daniel Dimitrov,SI,2,1:/home/SI/s62121:/bin/bash
s62133:x:1276:504:Ivaylo Ivanov,SI,2,2:/home/SI/s62133:/bin/bash
s62160:x:1277:504:Veniyana Tsolova,SI,2,3:/home/SI/s62160:/bin/bash
s62199:x:1278:504:Nikola Petrov,SI,2,5:/home/SI/s62199:/bin/bash
s62219:x:1279:504:Viliyan Ivanov,SI,2,6:/home/SI/s62219:/bin/bash
s62234:x:1280:504:Viktoriya Dobreva,SI,2,3:/home/SI/s62234:/bin/bash
s855264:x:1281:504:Toni Dupkarski,SI,4,2:/home/SI/s855264:/bin/bash
s81555:x:1282:503:Elena Georgieva,KN,2,0:/home/KN/s81555:/bin/bash
s81585:x:1283:503:Stela Marinova,KN,2,0:/home/KN/s81585:/bin/bash
s81441:x:1284:503:Vesela Plamenova Borislavova , KN, k2, g7:/home/KN/s81441:/bin/bash
s81644:x:1285:503:Viktor Rusev, KN, k2, g7:/home/KN/s81644:/bin/bash
s81628:x:1286:503:Iliyan Yordanov Yordanov, KN, k2, g6:/home/KN/s81628:/bin/bash
s81490:x:1287:503:Yana Spasova, KN, k2, g6:/home/KN/s81490:/bin/bash
```

[image]

What I have tried is using awk to find the row that meets the criteria and use NR to get the numbers of the other rows needed, but seems I am missing something.

Here is the command I used:

```
cat thefmifile.txt | awk -F ':' '$1==s62234 {for (x = NR -2; x <= NR + 2; x++){print}}'
```

Output is in the below screenshot.

[image]

And this is the desired output:

```
s62199:x:1278:504:Nikola Petrov,SI,2,5:/home/SI/s62199:/bin/bash
s62219:x:1279:504:Viliyan Ivanov,SI,2,6:/home/SI/s62219:/bin/bash
s62234:x:1280:504:Viktoriya Dobreva,SI,2,3:/home/SI/s62234:/bin/bash
s855264:x:1281:504:Toni Dupkarski,SI,4,2:/home/SI/s855264:/bin/bash
s81555:x:1282:503:Elena Georgieva,KN,2,0:/home/KN/s81555:/bin/bash
```

When it is {print x} it shows the numbers of the lines I need, but is there some way to access the lines of the file as elements in array and just to use this 'x' as an index (e.g. something like NR[x])?

Or Is there some other way to retrieve these rows? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v n=2 -F':' '$1=="s62234"{for (i=0;i<n;i++) print buf[(NR+i)%n]; c=n+1} c&&c--; {buf[NR%n]=$0}' file
s62199:x:1278:504:Nikola Petrov,SI,2,5:/home/SI/s62199:/bin/bash
s62219:x:1279:504:Viliyan Ivanov,SI,2,6:/home/SI/s62219:/bin/bash
s62234:x:1280:504:Viktoriya Dobreva,SI,2,3:/home/SI/s62234:/bin/bash
s855264:x:1281:504:Toni Dupkarski,SI,4,2:/home/SI/s855264:/bin/bash
s81555:x:1282:503:Elena Georgieva,KN,2,0:/home/KN/s81555:/bin/bash
```

`buf[]` is just an array storing the `n` lines preceding the current line so those can be printed when your `$1=="s62234"` condition is met. `c&&c--;` represents a true condition which will cause awk to print (the default action) the current line plus `n` subsequent lines due to `c=n+1` also being set when your condition is met - i.e. it'll print the current line and decrement `c` until `c` reaches zero.

Comment: just tried it and works perfectly as well, thank you a lot! Can you please explain to me the 'buf' and 'c&&c--' things as I am a beginner and actually never met this by now?

Comment: You're welcome. I added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, simple `grep` could handle this task.

```
grep -A2 -B2 '^s62234:' Input_file
```

Also more accurately you could try following to match exact string with `grep`:

```
grep -C2  '^s62234:' Input_file
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 working perfectly and much simple, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That's easily doable with grep:

```
-B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
-A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
-C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
-NUM                      same as --context=NUM
```

With awk, you could do something like this:

```
awk -F ':' '$1==s62234{print l2;print l1;a=3}a&&a-->0{print}{l2=l1;l1=$0}' thefmifile.txt
```

You can handle the number of before-lines dynamically by storing them in an array and using a loop.

Comment: @steffen the awk did not work, but the grep is a good idea, thank you!

Comment: @EdMorton The op wanted awk, so it's maybe not worth working on it

Comment: Thank you, it works! Can you please provide some explanation as for a beginner?

Comment: @Victoria Yes, I'm currently only with my mobile phone, so I'll write later. . a-- however decrements for each line and is true while positive (>0).

Comment: FWIW the reason I use `a&&a--` instead of `a-->0` is that for a huge file `a--` could wrap around and become positive again.