# GNU awk weirdness with array indexing in loop

Tags: awk

I was drafting a solution to a question earlier ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314655/linux-print-range-of-rows-if-a-condition-is-met-in-awk) actually), a simplified version:

```
$ echo {a..g} | tr ' ' '\n' |  # create some data
  awk  -v s=e '{               # search string as an argument
      for(i=1;i<=2;i++)        # keep 2 last records in a
          a[i]=a[i+1]          # this is the problematic part later
      a[3]=$1                  # hash the current record into a
  }
  $1==s {                      # once there is a match
      for(i=1;i<=3;i++)        # output from the hash
          print a[i]
  }'
```

Output:

```
c
d
e
```

Being me I had to try and make it a few bytes shorter (remove `i++` from the `for` and `a[i+1]`-> `a[++i]`:

```
$ echo {a..g} | tr ' ' '\n' | 
gawk -v s=e '{
    # i=1; while(i<=2)  # fails with while also
    for(i=1;i<=2;)      # i++ moved
        a[i]=a[++i]     # ... here
    a[3]=$1
}
$1==s {
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        print a[i]
}'
```

But the output failed on GNU awk:

```
    

e
```

After a while of wondering I switched to mawk and it worked. It also worked on Busybox awk but failed on awk-20121220. Any idea what causes the behaviour? Also, if you guys have a more descriptive idea for the title, feel free to change it.

Comment: You can simplify your script to `BEGIN{ a[1]=5; a[2]=15; a[++i]+=a[++i]; print a[1], a[2] }` to reproduce the same behaviour. Gawk evaluates the part after `=` the first, I don't know why.

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah, that pretty much explains it.

Comment: Lol, so how do I obfuscate this, `for(i=2;i<=3;) a[i+=2]=a[i--]` didn't work. :D:D After midnight is definitely not the time to think about this...

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=2;) a[i++]=a[i+1]`, `for(i=1;i<=2;) a[i-1]=a[++i]`, or just rewind the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Assignment-Ops.html):

> **It is up to the implementation as to which expression is evaluated first, the lefthand or the righthand.** Consider this example:
>
> ```
> i = 1
> a[i += 2] = i + 1
> ```
>
> The value of `a[3]` could be either two or four.